# ng grid -- How I can hide the filter text bar

Tags: filter, show-hide, ng-grid

Based in this example I would like to hide the filter texbox and make it appear only after double click the column name.

[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uw28KUbIOtDps2GaJahb?p=preview)

Where I could start?? :)
thanks.

Edit:

thanks to the advice of mainguy I was able to complete an example http://plnkr.co/edit/euSlVib5POkjAAe2Ucml?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (watch out for the variable `fv` (short for filtervisible):

Change the input in the headertemplate

```
<input type="text" ng-show="fv" ng-click="stopClickProp($event)" placeholder="Filter..." ng-model="col.filterText" ng-style="{ 'width' : col.width - 14 + 'px' }" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; bottom: 30px; left: 0; bottom:0;"/>
```

Add `fv` to your controllers scope.

```
$scope.fv=false; //initially closed
```

Add a toogle function for `fv` in the onDoubleClick handler of the ngGridDoubleClick plugin.

```
self.scope.$parent.fv=!self.scope.$parent.fv;
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SqEWu1Xo0V6lHHr2bkyE?p=preview). Not perfect because you have to find a way to adjust sizes but it may give you a hint on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the double click plugin; however, you could make the double click action toggle a scope level Boolean variable that you reference in a ng-show (or `ng-hide` or `ng-if`) attribute of the input tag of the header cell template to control the visibility of the filter.

In your main.js:

```
$scope.filterVisible = false; // hidden initially
```

Within the double click handler:

```
$scope.filterVisible = !$scope.filterVisible;
```

In your header cell template:

```
<input ng-show="filterVisible" type="text" ng-click="stopClickProp($event)" placeholder="Filter..." ng-model="col.filterText" ng-style="{ 'width' : col.width - 14 + 'px' }" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; bottom: 30px; left: 0; bottom:0;"/>
```

You will probably want to make more than one scope level Boolean (or perhaps even better, an array of Booleans) to handle toggling the filter for multiple/all of the columns in your grid.

Comment: $scope is not available in the plugin, that's why I used self.scope.$parent. Out of interest, how do you inject it? Because I think that would be better than to refer to an unknown parent.

Comment: hello here a little modifications